# Paypal vs braintree for user to user payments

Tags: paypal, payment, braintree

I need a solution that allows UserA to make a payment to UserB. UserA is a registered account in a web service that has their information stored in the "vault". UserB has no registered account and would simply pay at checkout by entering a valid card number. The web service would take 2% of the payment that goes to I guess a separate account for the website.

I am trying to wrap my head around which payment service to use as this is the first time I am creating a service with money transactions involved. I like Braintree specifically from what I see:

- Free up to first 50k (good for a small cloud based web service)
- Drop in UI that handles the encryption side of thigns for me (so it seems)

My question is my solution requirements need me to seemily split up the transaction that UserB pays from a card into two places - a portion to UserA and a portion to the web service. Does Brain tree offer a solution that makes this possible as I see it is with Paypal [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/)

Just looking for a quick link to the documentation.

Comment: Is it correct to say that UserA is business/corporate account and UserB is customer? Are you saying that you want UserB to pay the transaction fee? Usually only UserA (business account) should be interacting with Braintree. And Braintree is doing a job on the behalf of UserA, so transaction fee should be charged toward UserA. If UserA would like UserB to be responsible for the charge. Just add transaction fee to the invoice. It's like shipping fee. I'm not completely clear on your requirement. You may find https://www.braintreepayments.com/products-and-features/marketplace useful.

Answer (score 3):

I think Braintree supports "Split & pay". Refer : [You can designate a service fee with each transaction and Braintree will disburse the appropriate funds to you and your sub-merchant..](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/overview)

And Paypal of course supports Adaptive payments. Refer : [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

I think all you need is in the above links.

Comment: Hi, i have checked the links above and not Braintree Marketplace nor PayPal Adaptive Payments seem to support cross payments, let say User A pays with PayPal account, Main Merchant gets his percentage, and User B receives the rest but in a bank account(not paypal). Same happens for the opposite situation, User A pays with credit card / Merchant part / User B receives with PayPal. Please let me know if there is any payment gateway or combination that allow to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've made already some applications with the requirements of yours, and if I was you, I would consider Paypal Adaptive payments, because through the API, you can select how you want to "split" the payment between the receivers.

[image: Something Like This]

check this page for the configurations : [page with configs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/)